# Uwsgi configuration - No module called site

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, python, uwsgi

I am trying to get uwsgi working in combination with nginx for a flask application. This is UWSGI ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
processes = 4
module = run:manager
virtualenv = /var/www/test/venv
chdir = /var/www/test
logto = uwsgi.log
```

In the directory **/var/www/test** I have this file **run.py**

```
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from app import app, db

if __name__ == "__main__":
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    manager = Manager(app)
    manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
    manager.run()
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Set PythonHome to /var/www/test/                                                                         
ImportError: No module named site
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, being new to uwsgi, I didn't understand where virtualenvs end up by default (under ~/.virtualkenvs directory). For my moztrap app, the appropriate configuration turned out to be:

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/testa.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
module = wsgi:application
processes = 2
wsgi-file = /home/ianh/moztrap/moztrap/deploy/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/ianh/.virtualenvs/moztrap
chdir = /home/ianh/moztrap
touch-reload = /home/ianh/moztrap/reload
```

I messed around with module and virtualenv, and this is the combination that worked for me. Note, the wsgi.py file contains the following.

```
"""WSGI entry-point for MozTrap."""

import os
import sys

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, base_dir)

# Set default settings and instantiate application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "moztrap.settings.default")

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

I also tried loading uwsgi using apt-get then pip, but didn't in the end need to do a symlink - so I preume its using the one apt-get installed.

Thanks mainly to the following (and a few others that lack of rep points wont let me thank):

- http://eshlox.net/en/2012/09/11/nginx-uwsgi-virtualenv-and-django-ubuntu-1204/ - got socket up, but had to adjust
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798105/uwsgi-cannot-find-python-module - correct use of home/virtualenv to point to .virtualenv/project dir